# How many independent random variables can be defined over a standard probability space.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider the probability space $(0,1)$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the uniform-distribution as the probability.

Is there a set of independent random variables defined on it with the largest possible cardinality? Since $\{X_k\}$ where $X_k:(0,1)\to\{0,1\}$ maps $t \in (0,1)$ to the $k^{\text{th}}$  digit in its binary expansion is a collection of independent random variables, such that set has to be at least countable.

Let me add an additional condition, the random variables have to be non-degenerate.

Comment: since, mutatis mutandis, they are orthoganol you cannot have more than a basis for $\mathbb L^2$, which is countable

Comment: All members need not have expectations.

Comment: that's covered by the mutantis mutandis, take any bounded 1-1 fctn of your independents.  They remain independent but are square integrable.

Comment: Ah thanks, I think I got it now, I was confused for a moment because independent random variables are not generally orthogonal with respect to the inner product $<X,Y>=E(XY)$ unless they have mean 0. So I assume you are considering the inner product space defined on the equivalence class generated by : $X \sim Y$ iff $X -Y = \text{constant}$ with probability 1, with the inner product $<[X],[Y]> = cov(X,Y)$ and non-degeneracy ensures that the distinct members must belong to distinct equivalence classes.

Comment: This seems to be the question "How many independent random variables can be defined over a standard probability space". Would you consider changing a title?

Comment: Yes that is a better title I will do so.